# pod install in react native app ios folder is not detecting dependencies of my npm package

Tags: react-native, npm, cocoapods, npm-install, react-native-ios

I have a npm package, my-package, intended to be used by plain react native apps with a few dependencies listed in my package.json and the first two require native modules:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.6.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
```

I also included a my-package.podspec file at the root folder, though it mentions nothing about my dependencies so I'm not sure if it's relevant. The only lines I included are source_files and a bunch of metadata like name, version, etc.

Now I want to test to see if it works in a plain react native app, so I created one and run `npm i -S my-package`, then `cd ios/ && pod install`. I was expecting `pod install` to link/install my dependencies to Podfile.lock, but none of them got added, and the console output also doesn't mention them:

```
::> pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 49 dependencies from the Podfile and 40 total pods installed.
```

I want to allow people who use my package to be able to just call `npm install my-package` and `pod install` and be good to go. Am I missing some steps here, or is this not possible?

Comment: i think you need to add package.json with the dependencies in you project directory. give it try.

Comment: @zippax sorry I'm not sure what you mean by adding it to my project directory. I'm using the package as dependency in my react native project with npm install, and my goal is to make it so that this is all I need to do + `pod install` in the ios folder

Comment: pod install only affected if the library required to be linked in React Native

Comment: yeah I understand, but two of the dependencies here are required to be linked in React Native - @react-native-async-storage/async-storage and react-native-get-random-values. For example, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values. So I don't understand why they are not being linked. I'm using react native 0.64.0

Comment: hmm, try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839070/4499844

Comment: I did see that post and have added a .podspec file to my package as well (mentioned in my question), but it didn't do anything...

Comment: @JiakanWang did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @AmitBattan unfortunately no - I ended up asking people using my npm package to also run npm install for those dependencies after installing my package